# Is it recommended to use mysql ndb cluster for transactional data ?

Tags: database, mysql-cluster

We are currently using mysql master slave architecture but with time we are facing issue of storing data on single machine and acaling the machine vertically to overcome that we want to shard data logically at the same time providing high read and write throughput. Is it right to use mysql ndb cluster for that or we can use some other options If yes please specify other options for the same.

Our data is growing exponentially we need support for that kind of data with ACID property support

Answer (score 0):

MySQL NDB Cluster can handle high read and write throughput.
It can shard data in up to 24 shards.
You need to store all indexed data in-memory. So this becomes
your limit in data sizes. A number of terabytes per cluster is
perfectly feasible, petabytes isn't.
It does support ACID property.

Comment: In mysql ndb cluster 7.4 we have the config property to control data to be kept in memory and also if we reduce the count of number of column to be index will that be fine for long term.